# Why doesn't TinyMCE work with asp textbox but html textarea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, tinymce

I am using a tinyMCE with asp.net webforms.

It works fine with html textarea but I don't want that. I want to integrate it with asp:textbox but it doesn't work with that.

I have changed mode to multiline, provided columns and rows but nothing works with it.

Help please.

Code:

```
 <script src='//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#txtBoxBody'
        });
    </script>

<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">
         Body
     </label>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxBody" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
```

Update: Textarea works fine but if i put runat="server" attribute in it then it stops working too.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ID of the rendered TextBox isn't `txtBoxBody`  if you view the page source you'll see it's something like `Body_txtBoxBody` depending on the structure of your code.

To get it to work you need to do something like this:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#<%=txtBoxBody.ClientID%>'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok sir thanks, it works but not completely since i have put these textboxes inside views. It appears at first time page loading but after postback or switching view it disappears. why ?

Comment: That's a new question in itself. I'd suspect it's a case of loosing state or something overriding the value(s) but without seeing the code, that's just guess work.

Comment: @HugoYates thank you sooo much for saving my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate of @hugo's answer:

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ID="TB" Enabled="true"></asp:TextBox>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#TB',
    });
</script>
```